# Vertically center div responsively

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to vertically center the nav panel responsively, so that it is centered on all screens that are ~940px and up. I found this article [CSS-Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/) but I have been unable to implement this with my current code effectively.

**html**

```
    <body>

    <!-- Header -->
    <div class="header">

        <a href="#"><i id="nav-button" class="fa fa-2x fa-navicon"></i></a>

        <header class="logo">
            <a href="index.html"><img src="../Assets/images/logo.png" alt=""></a>
        </header>

        <a href="#"><i id="account-control" class="fa fa-2x fa-user"></i></a>

    </div>

<!-- Content Wrapper-->
<div class="wrapper">

    <!--  Content  -->
    <div id="content">
    </div>

    <!-- Collapsible Menu -->
    <div id="nav-sidebar">

        <div class="nav-items">

            <nav class="mainmenu">
                <ul>
                    <li class="active"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-dashboard" alt="Dashboard"></i></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-dollar" alt="Billing"></i></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-support" alt="Support"></i></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-cubes" alt="Servers"></i></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-cogs" alt="Settings"></i></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-bar-chart-o" alt="Reports"></i></a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>

        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
/* Core */
*, *:before, *:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  display: block;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.42857;
  color: black;
  background-color: white;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-margin-before: 0em;
  -webkit-margin-after: 0em;
  -webkit-padding-start: 0px;
}

.wrapper {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 75px;
  z-index: 0;
}

#content {
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 0;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}

/* Header */
.header {
  background-color: white;
  width: 100%;
  height: 75px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  box-shadow: 1px 0 1px #bdc3c7;
}

#nav-button {
  color: #555c60;
  position: absolute;
  left: 40px;
  top: 35%;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.2s;
  transition: transform 0.2s;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

#nav-button.nav-button-open {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.2s;
  transition: transform 0.2s;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

.logo {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

#account-control {
  color: #555c60;
  position: absolute;
  right: 40px;
  top: 35%;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.2s;
  transition: transform 0.2s;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
/* Navigation Sidebar */
#nav-sidebar {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 80px;
  background: none;
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 1;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
  -moz-transform: translateX(-100%);
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}
#nav-sidebar:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  content: '';
  opacity: 1;
}
#nav-sidebar:before {
  content: '';
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.nav-sidebar-open #nav-sidebar {
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform;
  -moz-transition-property: -webkit-transform;
  transition-property: transform;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
  -moz-transform: translateX(0);
  transform: translateX(0);
  -webkit-transition-speed: 0.2s;
  -moz-transition-speed: 0.2s;
  transition-speed: 0.2s;
}
.nav-sidebar-open #nav-sidebar:after {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}

.nav-items {
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #bdc3c7;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.mainmenu ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.mainmenu ul li {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}
.mainmenu ul li a {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #555c60;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -webkit-transition: background .4s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: background .4s ease-in-out;
  transition: background .4s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition-property: color,text;
  -webkit-transition-duration: .3s, .3s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: linear, ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition-property: color,text;
  -moz-transition-duration: .3s;
  -moz-transition-timing-function: linear, ease-in-out;
  -o-transition-property: color,text;
  -o-transition-duration: .3s, .3s;
  -o-transition-timing-function: linear, ease-in-out;
}
.mainmenu ul li a:hover, .mainmenu ul li a:active {
  background: #3498db;
  color: white;
  -webkit-transition: background .4s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: background .4s ease-in-out;
  transition: background .4s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition-property: color,text;
  -webkit-transition-duration: .3s, .3s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: linear, ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition-property: color,text;
  -moz-transition-duration: .3s;
  -moz-transition-timing-function: linear, ease-in-out;
  -o-transition-property: color,text;
  -o-transition-duration: .3s, .3s;
  -o-transition-timing-function: linear, ease-in-out;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
.mainmenu ul li a:first-child {
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}
.mainmenu ul li a:last-child {
  border-bottom: none;
}
.mainmenu ul li a i {
  margin: 20px;
}
```

**js**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

/* Sidebar */

    $('#nav-button').click(function() {
        $('#nav-button').toggleClass('nav-button-open');
        $('body').toggleClass('nav-sidebar-open');
        return false;
    });
});(jQuery);
```

P.S. (Don't be afraid of 190 lines of CSS, ~90 lines are CSS transitions that you can ignore.)

Also, here is the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZXRSn/) for you to play around with. Thank you so much for your help ahead of time.

Comment: Instead of just dumping all of your code here, why don't you post only the parts relevant to your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing it's the panel that slides out you want to be vertically aligned to the height of the view port if the view port is 940px or wider. I was unsure about other things and so I managed to achieve this but I had to clean it up a bit. Feel free to use parts you need and discard the other. It's not ever a good idea to position:fix the wrapper, not sure why you did this. Also don't know why you had a display:block on the body.

### DEMO: http://jsbin.com/zaguzo/1

Same html, same jQuery

**You may also want to add a min-height, this is a demo of that: http://jsbin.com/wegow/1**

The most relevant is the following but many other things need to be adjusted as well:

```
/* --- added --- */
@media (min-width:940px) { 

    #nav-sidebar {
        top: 50%;
        margin-top: -213px;
        /*height of total of this div by 2 minus 1/2 height of header */
    }
}
```

**CSS**

```
*,
*:before,
*:after {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body,
html {
    margin: 0; /* -- added  -- */
    padding: 0; /* -- added  -- */
}

body {
    font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.42857;
    color: black;
    background-color: white;
}

ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

/* -- wrapper not needed .wrapper {} -- */

#content {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 0;
    padding:95px 20px 20px 20px;
    transition: padding .5s ease-in-out;

}

.nav-sidebar-open #content {padding-left:100px;}


/* Header */

.header {
    background-color: white;
    height: 75px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 2;
    box-shadow: 1px 0 1px #bdc3c7;
    width: 100%;
}

#nav-button {
    color: #555c60;
    position: absolute;
    left: 40px;
    top: 35%;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.2s;
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.2s;
    transition: transform 0.2s;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

#nav-button.nav-button-open {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.logo {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
}

#account-control {
    color: #555c60;
    position: absolute;
    right: 40px;
    top: 35%;
}

/* Navigation Sidebar */

#nav-sidebar {
    position: fixed;
    top:75px;
    left: -88px;
    width: 80px;
    background: none;
    z-index: 1;
    transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
}

.nav-sidebar-open #nav-sidebar {
  left:0;
}

.nav-items {
    position: relative;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #bdc3c7;
}

.mainmenu ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.mainmenu ul li {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
}

.mainmenu ul li a {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    color: #555c60;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    width: 100%;
  background:#fff;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}


/* --- added --- */
@media (min-width:940px) { 

    #nav-sidebar {
        top: 50%;
        margin-top: -213px;
        /*height of total of this div by 2 minus 1/2 height of header */
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes I did want the slide-out panel to be vertically aligned to the viewport, you are spot on. :)

Thank you for pointing out other things wrong with my code, I am relatively new to all of this so it's nice to see what I do wrong, best practices, etc.

Comment: How did you come up with the `margin-top: -213px;`? Your notation there isn't exactly clear.

Comment: Height of the total nav items divided by 2 then you minus half the height of the header

Comment: And it's visual height, I used my tool thingy that comes with FF web dev tools, otherwise it looks off if you do 6 x 8 since you had padding there.

Comment: Unless you're supporting legacy browsers, AFIK you only need transition and not the other prefixes. See http://caniuse.com/#search=transition

Comment: Oh wow! That will save so much time. Thank you so much for your information. :)

Any more tips you can throw my way? XD

Comment: I really love minimal styles so it's nice to use the minimal style in my code too, so I am always happy to find ways to cut things out that do not affect the user experience or are not needed. Do you know of any tools that help clean up erroneous code?

Comment: No, I don't, because things change so often I just refer to caniuse.com and have a good memory, plus I  read the manual/docs and just keep up on stuff.

Comment: Well I thank you very much for going the extra mile on this question. Most people just patch the problem at hand and do not point out the problem with the entire bit of code.

Comment: Oh one more thing, is there a specific reason why you used a push menu on the example you provided other than sticking with my slide menu?

Comment: But it all works together often times and lots of answers are not so hot but voting them down takes away from my rep, so I don't do it.

Comment: I really didn't change much except adding a padding on content when the class is toggled, I don't like things to get covered up, that's all.